# error: cannot access InternalTokenProvider (Firebase/GooglePlayServices)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services, firebaseui

In my app where I use firebase, firebase-ui, google maps, among others, it worked perfectly. **I want to update to the latest version of each library and install Firebase Performance.**

The **error** I get is:

```
error: cannot access InternalTokenProvider
class file for com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider not found
```

And when I click on this error it sends me to an Activity to this line:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            //signin things
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "app.example.asd"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.3.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.42.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.42.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'

    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    //kt y rxjava
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
    //lib en kt
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Can anyone detect where the problem is in my dependencies?** Thank you

**UPDATE**
With Peter's help I was able to correct the error, changing from firebase-auth:16.0.1 to firebase-auth:17.0.0.

Now I'm getting another error when I install and open my app, this is it:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:98)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
```

The error appears the first time I use this line in my app:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you are pulling in `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5` via the dependency on `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.3.2` (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/4.3.2)

Try adding this to your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
```

Also, generally check you are using the latest versions, which can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

**NOTE:** This is based on the new error in your update after changing from firebase-auth:16.0.1 to firebase-auth:17.0.0

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

Into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had gone back to my build.gradle working file and was developing another module. Please check the update in my question.

Comment: Also upgrade other firebase dependencies to `17.x.x`+

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade everything(Firebase Auth, Cloud, etc) to the latest versions by just hovering mouse over it.

Answer (score 1):

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
```

or:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
```

Sync to this version and see.
If not, upgrade the Firebase tools on Android Studio.